# Debian Squeeze Preseed Installation “The current kernel doesn't support the Logical Volume Manager. You may need to load the lvm-mod module.”

Tags: debian, virtualization, libvirt

I'm attempting to install Debian Squeeze via an [instalinux.com](http://www.instalinux.com/) image pre-seeded with more or less default settings. (Only notable addition is the `openssh` server, which is a clickable option in the *Instalinux* interface)

It is however raising the error:

```
The current kernel doesn't support the Logical Volume Manager. 
You may need to load the lvm-mod module.
```

part way through the installation. I've done a lot of reading and found out from this [widely re-posted debian mailing list thread](http://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2012/01/msg00340.html). That it can be a problem of `linux` and `initrd.gz` being out of sync between the netboot and the prepared ISO.

I have to open the ISO anyway in order to patch the `isolinux.conf` not to prompt, so patching these files wouldn't be a massive hardship, I've included the relavant parts of my `Makefile` below:

```
provision: tmp/empty.img isos/debian-squeeze-preseed-unattended.iso
    virt-install -n demo -r 256 -vcpus=1 -f tmp/empty.img \
    -b br0 --accelerate -v -c isos/debian-squeeze-preseed.iso \
    --os-type=linux --os-variant=debiansqueeze --nographics \
    --extra-args="auto=true hostname=demo domain= \
    file=preseed.txt text console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200"

isos/debian-squeeze-preseed-unattended.iso:
    mkdir -p tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed
    mount -t iso9660 -o loop isos/debian-squeeze-preseed.iso tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed
    cp -a tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed/ tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed-unattended
    echo "timeout 5" >> tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed-unattended/isolinux.cfg
    #
    # These two curl commands relate to the problem here http://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2012/01/msg00340.html
    #
    curl -0 ftp://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/i386/linux > tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed-unattended/linux
    curl -0 ftp://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/i386/initrd.gz > tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed-unattended/initrd.gz
    genisoimage -l -r -J -V "LinuxCOE" -b isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -c boot.cat -o $@ \
    tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed-unattended
    umount tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed
    rm -r tmp/debian-squeeze-preseed
```

Reading through the noise, you can see that I'm opening the ISO and patching a timeout into the isolinux.conf, and trying to update the `linux` and `initrd.gz` files, however to no avail.

Whether I try and boot in VirtualBox with the preseed image (without modification), or whether I boot my *unattended* image in libvirt, or virtualbox, the results are always the same “The current kernel doesn't support the Logical Volume Manager.”

I'm not certain what version of Squeeze the *Instalinux* tool is giving me, but I've a *feeling* that it was 6.0.3, but now that I've gone looking for it, I can't find it. I was able to extract the following from the post-failed-installation console:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Debian
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Debian GNU/Linux Installer"
DISTRIB_RELEASE="6.0 (squeeze) - installer build 20110106+b1"
X_INSTALLATION_MEDIUM=netboot
```

I'm missing a patch release in the information out of the image, but given that the timestamps on the [FTP directory](ftp://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/i386/) are from 26-09-2012, that's a long time for things to get out of sync.

I'm wondering where to look next for a solution, whether I even need a preseeded ISO, or whether there might be some nicer workarounds.